# What is the recommended way to avoid hotlinking images?

Tags: discussion, image

I've just posted two answers from guides providing good answers. On both of them are  images explaining the steps.

I can't find the reference. But somewhere on Ask Ubuntu it was said that it's better to copy a guide than to link them, since you can never know when the linked is going to be offline.

With that philosophy I thought that by including a image by selecting a image-URL it would copy it over from the original guide and link that.

Now this isn't the case. By adding a image by URL from another page you will it hotlink the image from the original source. If the image changes or the server of this page goes down, the image-link will be broken.

What is the recommended way to avoid hotlinking images?

Comment: just make sure it is from source that you can reuse in that manner, some sites don't allow this reuse of content - or require linking back to their image. (since you are essentially re-licensing the content to CC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click img:

[image]

Then hit from the web:

[image]

Paste the hotlink and VOILA!

Image from that was in Flickr now is in Imgur.

[image]

Comment: I was certain this would hotlink the image from the given URL. It doesn't? How is this different from procedure I gave in my question? To be precise,I **did** meddle with the markdown after including it this way... does it copy the image soewhere else if i don't?

Comment: Ahh well.. adding it with the shown method will **allways** copy the image to imgur and link from there. The hotlinked images came from me writing directly ![Alt-Text][Copied-URL] and thus were linked as given. Feeling a bit stupid now ;-)

Comment: @MadMike nope, imgur take the image and import them to their servers.